# Can I prove with L'hopital Rule that a function tends to $\infty$?

Tags: calculus

Prove that the  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2}{ \ln(n)}$$ tends to $\infty$.

Denote $f(x) = n^2 ,\ g(x) = \ln(n)$

[image]

Thanks

Comment: So, what's your question? You seem to be done.

Comment: @S.C.B. l'hoptial rule demands that the limit of f'(x) / g'(x) has to exist. here it's infinity

Comment: That's a bit unclear within your question.

Comment: Limit exists and is equal to infinity.

Comment: If the limit doesn't exist that's perfectly fine, L'Hospitals rule only indicates if an indeterminate form has a limit or doesn't exist

Comment: @kingW3 so basically the limit doesn't have to be a rational number for example it can be infinity too am I right?

Comment: @user401575, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Hôpital's_rule#General_form -- the version there allows the limit to be an *extended* real number, which includes infinity.

Comment: You seem to confusing $x$ with $n$ here. $f(x)=n^2$ is a constant function. You mean either $f(n)=n^2$ of $f(x)=x^2$. Similarly, $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x)=f(x)$. You mean either $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$ or $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.

Comment: got it. Thanks guys!